# Rails error - Booking unsuccessful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an Event app using Rails. I've recently changed around my bookings controller to accomodate events which are free. This side of the app seems to work fine but when I try a test booking for a paid event the app defaults to 'booking unsuccessful' after I complete the payment submission form.

I'm not really sure why this is happening. Here's my controller logic -

```
def new

        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = Booking.new
        @booking.user = current_user



    end

    def create
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
        @booking.user = current_user


            if 
                @booking.save
                flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
                redirect_to event_booking_path(@event, @booking)
            else
                flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
                render "new"
            end

    end

    def show
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    end


    def update

        if @booking.update(booking_params)
            redirect_to event_booking_path(@event, @booking) , notice: "Booking was successfully updated!"
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end




    private

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :booking_number, :quantity, :event_id, :stripe_charge_id, :total_amount)
    end
```

And in my model I have this -

**Booking.rb**

```
   class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user


  before_create :set_booking_number 

     validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
     validates :total_amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
     validates :quantity, :total_amount, :booking_number, presence: true

  def set_booking_number
    self.booking_number = "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase
  end



    def booking
        # Don't process this booking if it isn't valid
        self.valid?

          if booking.is_free?
            self.total_amount = event.price_pennies.nil?
            save!
          end



            begin
                        self.total_amount = event.price_pennies * self.quantity
                        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
                            amount: total_amount,
                            currency: "gbp",
                            source: stripe_token, 
                            description: "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}")
                        self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
              self.booking_number = "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase
                        save!
                    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
                    errors.add(:base, e.message)
                    false
                end

  end
end
```

So, for some reason its not saving or there's something else not right. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: See the error message on view by displaying validation errors. `flash[:error] = @booking.errors.full_messages.join(',')`

Comment: Your code seems incomplete ... not sure where your booking method in your Booking model is called from but it doesn't appear to be from your controller. Also would be handy to see what validations you have in your model.

Comment: Full Booking model code is now added with validations. Any thoughts? Rather than booking.is_free? should it be an if/else statement with event.is_free? then 'else' paid method code? (see other comments below)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the complete code? Your "booking.rb" seems completely wrong.

You are defining a method "booking", but I don't see you calling it anywhere.
Except maybe in the booking-method itself when you execute

```
if booking.is_free?
```

Did you mix something up there?

Comment: Do you mean in the controller? With @booking.is_free? In the model I'm trying to differentiate between a free booking and a paid booking. In my events model I have an if_free? Attribute but not in booking so I'm trying to separate them here.

Comment: okay. But in your Booking.rb you define a method "booking" and in line 4 you call "booking.is_free?" but this booking only references the method itself. That's why I asked if the code is complete. Or did you mean to call event.is_free? or some kind of @booking.is_free?

Comment: maybe the complete Booking.rb would be helpful

Comment: I'm doing an if statement so if it's free - save it. If it's not free move on. But I think this is the crux of the issue - how to separate free from paid.

Comment: The only other code on the booking model are some validations. There are no other methods.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. My guess you have some relation between Booking and Event (Booking belongs_to Event). So your if statement should be like `if self.event.is_free?`

Comment: Ah yes - sorry. Yes, correct Events have_many bookings and bookings belong_to Events.

Comment: no other methods? But I guess you have a `before_save(:booking)` or how is that method "booking" being called?

Comment: I have no before_save methods in either my model or controller.

Comment: Please update your question with the complete Booking.rb

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's see.

I think you need something like this:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
  before_create :set_booking_number
  ### new
  before_save(:set_total_amount)

  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
  validates :total_amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
  validates :quantity, :total_amount, :booking_number, presence: true
  ### new
  validate(:validate_booking)

  def set_booking_number
    self.booking_number = "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase
  end

  def set_total_amount
    # does event.is_free? exist? if not: either define .is_free? or use self.event.price_pennies.nil? or self.event.price_pennies.to_i == 0
    if self.event.is_free?
      # I am guessing total_amount is an Int but you are assigning a boolean
      # self.total_amount = event.price_pennies.nil?
      # should be
      self.total_amount = 0
    else
      self.total_amount = event.price_pennies * self.quantity
      begin
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
          amount: total_amount,
          currency: "gbp",
          source: stripe_token, 
          description: "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}")
        self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
      rescue Stripe::CardError => e
        # if this fails stripe_charge_id will be null, but in case of update we just set it to nil again
        self.stripe_charge_id = nil
        # we check in validatition if nil
      end
      # booking number was already set, see set_booking_number
      # self.booking_number = "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase
    end
  end

  # is suppose to be a validation, so I renamed it
  # def booking
  def validate_booking
    # Don't process this booking if it isn't valid
    # will be called on .save anyway
    # self.valid?

    # I pushed this to set_total_amount (called by before_save)
    #    if booking.is_free?
    #      self.total_amount = event.price_pennies.nil?
    # Why call save! ? with "!" it will cast an exception if invalid
    #      save!
    #    end

    # also pushed to set_total_amount since this has nothing to do with validation
    #      begin
    #                  self.total_amount = event.price_pennies * self.quantity
    #                  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    #                      amount: total_amount,
    #                      currency: "gbp",
    #                      source: stripe_token, 
    #              description: "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}")
    #                  self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
    #        self.booking_number = "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase
    #                  save!
    #              rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    #              errors.add(:base, e.message)
    #              false
    #          end

    # stripe_charge_id must be set for not free events
    unless self.event.is_free?
      return !self.stripe_charge_id.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

this is of course not tested. But give it a go.

I hope my comments are clear.

Comment: Thanks for this. It all looks good. I've already implemented some changes of my own and integrated some of yours - the main issue with the above answer is that 'save!' was needed in order to pass the proper params in the controller. I'll post my final code shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally broke through with some work on the params and work on the model code. Here's the final code in my controller and model -

**Booking.rb**

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
  before_create :set_booking_number


  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
  validates :total_amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

  validate(:validate_booking)

  def set_booking_number
    self.booking_number = "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase
  end

  def set_booking

    if self.event.is_free?
      self.total_amount = 0
      save!
    else
      self.total_amount = event.price_pennies * self.quantity
      begin
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
          amount: total_amount,
          currency: "gbp",
          source: stripe_token, 
          description: "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}")
        self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
        save!
      rescue Stripe::CardError => e
        self.stripe_charge_id = nil

      end
    end
  end

    unless self.event.is_free?
      return !self.stripe_charge_id.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

**Bookings_controller.rb**

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!



    def new
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
        @booking = Booking.new(params[:booking])
        @booking.user = current_user



    end

    def create

        # actually process the booking
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
        @booking.user = current_user


            if 
                @booking.set_booking
                flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
                redirect_to event_booking_path(@event, @booking)
            else
                flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
                render "new"
            end

            if @event.is_free?
                @booking.save(booking_params)
            end
    end

    def show
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    end


    def update

        if @booking.update(booking_params)
            redirect_to event_booking_path(@event, @booking) , notice: "Booking was successfully updated!"
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end




    private

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :booking_number, :quantity, :event_id, :stripe_charge_id, :total_amount)
    end






end
```